# get dynamic select options to select multiple numbers from range 0 to n in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multidimensional-array, frontend, angular-ngselect

I want to get the range from the user and based on the range the user can select multiple options from the select statement using angular js. Please help

```
<input type="text" ng-model="range" placeholder="enter range">
<select multiple name="selectValue" id="selectValue" ng-model="selectValue" >
  <option value="i" ng-repeat="i in range">hi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Do you have any criteria for making elements from that range? Like if the user types in 1-50, then how many values would be there in your select list? What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @SiddAjmera yes, the range should be from 1-20 , consider them as the roll no, since different class can have different numbers of student. The user should be able to  selects the roll numbers(multiple)

Answer (score 0):

I'd just take two different values. One for the `ng-model` of the input(`rangeInput`) and the other one for the `ng-model` of the select list(`selectValue`).

Then I can listen to the `enter` press using `ng-keyup="$event.which === 13 && vm.addToRange()"`

In the controller's `addToRange()` method, I'll `split` range input with `-`, `reverse` it to get the max roll-number, change it to type `number` by prepending the expression with `+`. That's what's happening here:

```
const total = +this.rangeInput.split('-').reverse()[0];
```

As soon as I get total, I can generate the `range` using `Array`'s `fill` method which will generate the Array for me. I'll then map the input to get start from 1 and increment the next element by 1. This is what the following line does:

```
this.range = Array(total).fill(1).map((x, y) => x + y);
```

Finally, I can reset the `range` input to an empty string.

Template:

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  ng-model="vm.rangeInput" 
  placeholder="enter range"
  ng-keyup="$event.which === 13 && vm.addToRange()">

<br>
<br>

<select 
  class="width"
  ng-change="vm.selectValueChanged()"
  multiple 
  name="selectValue" 
  id="selectValue" 
  ng-model="vm.selectValue">
  <option ng-value="i" ng-repeat="i in vm.range">{{i}}</option>
</select>
```

Controller:

```
class HomeCtrl {
  constructor($scope) {
    'ngInject';

    this.range = [];
    this.rangeInput = '';
    this.selectValue = '';

    this.addToRange = () => {
      const total = +this.rangeInput.split('-').reverse()[0];
      this.range = Array(total).fill(1).map((x, y) => x + y);
      this.rangeInput = '';
    }

    this.selectValueChanged = () => {
      console.log(this.selectValue);
    }

  }
}

export default HomeCtrl;
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-multiple-select) for your ref.

**PS:** I'm assuming that the roll-numbers would start from 1.